# Does Catias 3dxml format contain CAD as Nurbs, or is it just a triangulated/polygonal mesh?

Tags: polygon, mesh, cad, catia, nurbs

I am curious if 3DXML is actually a Mesh or if it is Nurbs. Is it limited when compared to a Catpart/Catproduct assembly? My background is not Cad so apologies if this isn't a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version 4.3 of the 3D XML format has only support für polygons, but not nurbs. The specification of the format can be downloaded from the 3DS website. https://www.3ds.com/3ds-passport/downloads/